# prove that 2 does not go into $n^2 – 2$ without a remainder for odd $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that $2$ does not go into $n^2 – 2$ without a remainder for odd $n$.

How do I approach this?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, what does this say about $n^2$?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, rewrite as $n=2k+1$ and substitute into the expression. Now you can see why $2$ does not go evenly into it

Comment: Ahh because no matter what number you plug in for k you will always end up with a odd number that 2 will not go evenly into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prove that $2$ does not go into $n^2-2$ without a remainder for odd $n$

This basically means: “Prove that for odd $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n^2-2$ is odd ($\Leftrightarrow$ leaves a remainder when filling it with $2$'s, saying it with your words).

The key here is to observe that if $n$ is odd, so is $n^2$, and therefore is $n^2-2$.

Let me give you a short formal proof for that:
$$\text{Let }n\in \mathbb{N}, n\text{ odd}\\
\implies \exists k\in\mathbb{N}: n=2k-1\\
\implies \exists k\in\mathbb{N}: n^2-2=\left(2k-1\right)^2-2=4k^2-4k+1-2\\
= 2\left(2k^2-2k-1\right)+1\\
\implies n^2-2 \text{ odd}$$
Quod erat demonstrandum.

To explain the *strategy*:
As I mentioned above, try to figure out in what way the term is “built” by $n$, and how the property of being even/odd affects this.

To prove this, a major thing to do is split the concerned variable into its divider and its remainder, which in this case means that you have to describe $n$ as $n=2k-1$ (divisible by $2$ with the remanider $1$), putting it into the term and see how you can split what you end up with *again* — as I did in the last step in the equation chain, factor out the divisor, in this case $2$, and look at what remainder you get  in this case $1$.

By the way, regarding the square of a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there holds even more: $n\text{ even}\Leftrightarrow n^2\text{ even}$, which you can try proving yourself.

**Hint**: You have to prove $n\text{ even}\implies n^2\text{ even}$ and $n\text{ odd}\implies n^2\text{ odd}$.

*Footnote*: $\exists$ is a common used shorthand notation for *“there exists”*

Comment: Wow I get it now...This was so easy..Lol I'm an idiot. The explanation was amazing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $n = 2m+1$ be an arbitrary odd integer and expand the square. Then analyze the structure of $n^2-2$

Comment: So are you saying expand the square which becomes (2m+1)^2 which becomes 4m^2 + 4m + 1 ... Then I should plug in odd numbers for n? So.. n = 2(1) + 1 = 3, n = 2(3)+1 = 7 , n = 2(5)+1 = 11?

Comment: @user3325915 no, you never plug in values for $n$; the power of the proof lies in $n$ being strictly arbitrary. I'm saying analyze the structure of $$n^2-2 = (2m+1)^2-2 \\ = 4m^2+4m-1$$ what can be said about $4m^2+4m$? for one, you can get a bit farther by writing $4m^2+4m = 2(2m^2+2m)$ Once you know what can be said of $2(2m^2+2m)$, what does that immediately suggest about $2(2m^2+2m)-1$?

Comment: so..I might be incorrect but.. You're saying something like 2(2m^2+2m) - 1 is essentially always going to be some odd number no matter what value you plug in so therefore 2 could never go into these numbers evenly?

Comment: @user3325915 You are exactly right! Writing out the quantity $2(2m^2+2m)$ makes it clear that the quantity is divisible by $2$. You can (optionally) let $2m^2+2m = p$ for some integer $p$. Hence your problem boils down to $n^2-2 = 2p-1$ and $2p-1$ is precisely the definition of an arbitrary odd integer. Hence, $2 \nmid (2p-1)$.